# Tabelas tipo GT não imprimindo dentro de loop in RMarkdown

Tags: r, tidyverse, rmarkdown

Estou programando um gerador de relatórios que exporta html. Eu uso dois arquivos, o primeiro é um loop que determinará o número de relatórios e dentro do meu modelo .Rmd eu tenho outro loop para imprimir várias tabelas.

O .Rmd abaixo funciona bem

```
---
title: "Report"
author: "Me"
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%d de %B de %Y')`"
output:
  html_document
---

# First Section    

{r , results='asis', echo=FALSE, message=FALSE}
library(tidyverse)
library(gt)

i=1

df <- cbind(m=c(rep(1,16),rep(2,16)),mtcars)

gears <- unique(df$gear)

for(g in gears)
{
  cat("## gear", g, "\n")
  
  print(
  df %>% filter(gear==g & m==i) %>%
    gt()
  )
}
```

A saída

[image: saida com tabelas]

mas seu eu gero o relatório a partir dos script R as tabelas não são impressas

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gt)

df <- cbind(m=c(rep(1,16),rep(2,16)),mtcars)

for (i in 1:2) 
{

  rmarkdown::render(
    'report_template_2.Rmd', output_file = paste0("report", 
                                                    "_",i, 
                                                  '.html'), encoding="UTF-8")
}
```

[image: saida sem tabelas]

Em tempo, outras impressões de tabelas usando o pacote GT ao logo do script são impressas normalmente.

Alguma idéia do que pode estar acontecendo?

Answer (score 3):

O RScript não localiza o Pandoc, precisa definir no arquivo de execução.
Verifique o diretório do pandoc com a função `Sys.getenv("RSTUDIO_PANDOC")`

Fiz alguns simplificações no exemplo.

`Rscript cron.R`

`cron.R`

```
Sys.setenv(RSTUDIO_PANDOC='/usr/lib/rstudio/bin/pandoc')
for (i in 1:2){
  rmarkdown::render('report.Rmd', 
  output_file = paste0("report","_", i, '.html'), encoding="UTF-8")
}
```

`report.Rmd`

````
---
title: "Report"
author: "Me"
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%d de %B de %Y')`"
output:
  html_document
---

# First Section    

```{r , results='asis', echo=FALSE, message=FALSE}
library(tidyverse)
library(gt)

df <- cbind(m=c(rep(1,16),rep(2,16)),mtcars)

gears <- unique(df$gear)

for(g in gears){
  cat("<h2><b>gear", g, "</b></h2>")
  df %>% filter(gear==g) %>% gt() %>% print
}
```
````

Comment: então, houve um avanço, mas não resolveu, agora eu vejo a tabela gt() na aba de View, mas ela continua não sendo gerada no html. Achei o diretorio do Pandoc que aqui está em Sys.setenv(RSTUDIO_PANDOC='C:/Program Files/RStudio/bin/pandoc'), la apenas isso >>> <p># First Section</p>
<h2>
<b>gear 4 </b>
</h2>
<h2>
<b>gear 3 </b>
</h2>
<h2>
<b>gear 5 </b>
</h2>

Answer (score 2):

A resposta que resolveu veio de uma colaboração na versão em inglês da questão (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66812874/printing-gt-table-inside-a-loop-with-rmarkdownrender-not-working) e que é usar

```
print(htmltools::tagList(df %>% gt()))
```